# Why won't gradle download this dependency from custom repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to download the DynamoDBLocal dependency from a custom repository.

Dependency: com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:1.11.86

The following repository contains the dependency: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release

I've checked that both the pom and jar are accessible in the repository by manually visiting these urls:

- https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release/com/amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/1.11.86/DynamoDBLocal-1.11.86.jar
- https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release/com/amazonaws/DynamoDBLocal/1.11.86/DynamoDBLocal-1.11.86.pom

I've added the repository to my build.gradle.kts file like so:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url = uri("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release")
    }
}
```

I've added the test dependency like so:

```
testImplementation("com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:1.11.86")
```

Now when I run a build I get the following error:

```
Could not find com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:1.11.86
```

How can I get gradle to download this dependency correctly?

Comment: What version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 7.1.1

Comment: Can't reproduce, works for me, even with 7.1.1

Answer (score 2):

this works for me, I'm using gradle 7.4.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name "DynamoDB Local Release Repository"
        url "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/release"
    }
}

...

testImplementation 'com.amazonaws:DynamoDBLocal:1.18.0'
```